# Solving $\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2}) +\arccos(x) = \text{arccot} \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right) - \arcsin( x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

If we have to find the solutions of equation

> $$\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2}) +\arccos(x) = \text{arccot} \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right) - \arcsin( x)$$

Using a triangle I rewrite it as

$$2 \arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)= 0$$

So this equation is satisfied when $x=\pm 1$

But I saw that $x=-1/2$ is also satisfying , then where I have missed the case .

I am totally stuck , how to find it .

Comment: Have you plotted both sides of the equation? [It looks to me like 1 is the only solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%28sqrt%281-x^2%29%29%2Barccos%28x%29+,+arccot%28sqrt%281-x^2%29%2Fx%29-arcsin%28x%29+from+-1+to+1)

Comment: @Wouter yes I have plotted both sides

Comment: How do you define $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ for $x<0?\;$  Continous or sign-symmetric? Maple uses the continous version and there is equality of both sides for all $x<0$.

Comment: @gammatester I have not defined at x<0 . But then how can I do it .

Comment: But you considered $x=-1, -1/2$ as solutions

Comment: @gammatester x = 1 , -1/√(2) , √(3)/2 are satisfying  , but I am not getting them

Comment: As already written: It depends on your definition of $\mathrm{arccot}(x)\,$ for negative arguments.
Do you compute $\mathrm{arccot}(-1)=\frac{3}{4}\pi\;$ or $\mathrm{arccot}(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}?\;$
For the first (continous) version see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions, compare with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+arccot%28x%29

Comment: Why not let $x=\cos(\phi)$ an then discuss the appropriate cases?

Comment: @gammatester arccot (-1) = 3π/4

Comment: @MichaelHoppe why only cos and by this I am not getting any result.

Comment: @user101522 You'll get $\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2})=\arcsin(|\sin(\phi)|)$ for instance.

Comment: E.g. for $x=-\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}$ the equation looks like
$\frac{1}{4}\pi + \frac{3}{4}\pi = \frac{3}{4}\pi - (-\frac{1}{4}\pi)$

Comment: @gammatester  the equation is satisfying . That means the value of x  is correct.

Comment: Yes I know. As already told all $-1\le x < 0$ are solutions, e.g. for $x=-\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ you have
$$\frac{1}{6}\pi + \frac{5}{6}\pi = \frac{2}{3}\pi - (-\frac{1}{3}\pi)$$

Comment: @gammatester but how can we prove all -1 <x<0  are the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightaway the problem reduces to  $$\text{arccot}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

As $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge0,$ using  the definition of [Principal Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)
 $0\le\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}\le\dfrac\pi2$

and consequently, $\dfrac\pi2\le\text{arccot}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\le\pi$

$\implies x\not>0$ but $x\ne0,$

let $-x=y>0$

$$\implies\text{arccot}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{-y}=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

$$\iff\dfrac\pi2-\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{-y}=\dfrac\pi2+\arccos y$$

As $\arctan(-u)=-\arctan u,$

$$\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y=\arccos y$$

Now as $y>0$ and let $\arccos y=v\implies\cos v=y$ and $0\le v<\dfrac\pi2$

and $\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y=\tan v\implies\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y=v=\arccos y$ as $0\le v<\dfrac\pi2$

So, we need $y>0\iff x<0$

Answer (score 2):

For $x<0$ set $x=\sin z$. Then you have
$$\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2})=\arcsin(\cos z)= \frac{1}{2}\pi - \arccos(\cos z)$$
$$\arccos(\sin z)= \frac{1}{2}\pi - \arccos(\cos z)$$
$$\arcsin x= \arcsin (\sin z)= z$$
$$\mathrm{arccot}(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x})=\mathrm{arccot}(\frac{\cos z }{\sin z})
=\mathrm{arccot}(\cot z) = \pi + z$$
(Note: The last expression would be $z$ for $z>0.$) Now compute the sums

$$\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2}) + \arccos x = \pi$$
$$\mathrm{arccot}(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x})- \arcsin x = \pi$$

So both sides equal $\pi$ for $x<0$